# YQL web scraping exceeding max allowed limit

Tags: javascript, yql

I'm using YQL to scrape data from a website but now the data has grown so large that it exceeds the limit that YQL allows, so all I get returned is a null result. I'm not sure how I should get the data now, since I'm not using any server-side technology.

This is a snippet of how I collect the data:

```
YUI().use('yql', function(Y) {
    Y.YQL('select * from htmlstring where ' +
        'url="http://website.com" 'and xpath="//div[contains(@class, \'name\')]"'
```

> Exception: Response from stream exceeded max:1539672 allowed limit:1536000

Comment: Have you tried paging? See https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/select.html#paging-table-limits .

Comment: Actually, that approach I linked to isn't very thread-safe: If someone else removes rows while you're paging, you may miss rows that weren't removed. (Or if they add rows you might get a row twice.) And you can't do it properly, since remote filters don't allow inequality comparisons. The best you can do is have overlapping pages so you can check for missing elements, then deduplicate locally. (Yahoo's website is fairly buggy, so I'm not surprised by deficiencies in their API.) But if you don't need very accurate results then maybe my original comment was good enough.

Comment: How would I try this? Is there anything I can swap out at the "select *" instead of the star?The result I normally get back is just plain HTML (all the divs that has class 'name' from the source of the website page). I then convert the HTML to a JSON object and iterate through it.

Comment: What's wrong with `*`? The documented examples don't use `*`, but that doesn't mean you can't. (Having said that, `*` is an unnecessary feature - it's quicker to write, but at the cost of bandwidth. Just list whichever columns you need. If the size limit is on bytes rather than rows, this should enable you to get more rows of response. But it's not a permanent solution - if the dataset keeps growing, you'll eventually run out of bandwidth again.)

Comment: And by the way, I'm assuming that the limit is on the size of an individual request. It might be a monthly or hourly limit or something - it's not clear to me. In that case paging won't help - you might have to pay money to Yahoo or something.

Comment: I tried both suggestions to limit the query but I'm still getting count 0 and results null (supposed to get count 1).